Would Darrell Royal have been allowed to keep Willie Nelson's Pedernales Country Club if he had paid the amount of the foreclosure on it?
This question is more about possible government overreach than a legal question, which I thought made it a better fit on the Stack Exchange Politics site since government and taxes are topics discussed there also. Even though answering it requires discussing a particular tax situation that happened when a friend of Willy Nelson's tried to help Nelson not lose a particular piece of his property (Nelson's recording studio compound) to the auctioneer while he was in the middle of a tax dispute with the IRS. But apparently the question fits better here.
An entry in Wikipedia reads as if the IRS vindictively stopped Nelson's friend from purchasing the property, but there was no attribution for that claim in the article. It also seems possible that the Wikipedia article is wrong and the IRS was simply following its own guidelines. But confirming this requires reading a few paragraphs of an IRS document and attempting to decipher it.
It seems like almost anyone could get into a similar situation, if for example the IRS seized a family property or essential business property, and sold it off while blocking anyone related to the owner from trying to purchase the property. But can and do they actually do that, perhaps by stretching their rules as an excuse? Below are the facts of the situation that I know of.
In the early 1990's Willie Nelson had issues with the IRS related to back taxes that he was assessed for some disallowed deductions that had been made in prior tax years. According to Wikipedia:

In 1990, the IRS seized most of Nelson's assets, claiming that he owed $32 million.

In 1991 the IRS auctioned off the 76-acre Pedernales Country Club outside of Austin, Texas which Nelson had purchased in 1979 and converted to a recording studio complex, complete with living accommodations for Nelson, family members, and employees.
According to a New York Times article at the time, former football coach and Nelson friend Darrell Royal purchased the property at the auction with a winning bid of $117,375. Stating at the time that he "wanted to see it stay open" and also admitting that he paid a "cheap price", although that wasn't something he controlled, it was an auction so that just means there weren't any higher bidders.
However according to the Wikipedia article,

Upon realizing that Royal bought the club for safekeeping, the IRS broke the deal, refunding him the money with a six percent interest.

The IRS then sold the property to some investors for $230,000. Nelson eventually did wind up being able to repurchase the property several years later.
I don't know if a reason for cancelling the sale was given by the IRS, but the Wikipedia article also stated that the IRS cancelled the sale within the 120 day "right of redemption" period of the IRS. According to the IRS web page on the topic (apparently last modified in 2016):

5.12.5.1 (06-07-2016)
Redemption Overview


The Internal Revenue Service has the right to redeem real property sold through a foreclosure action initiated by a third party that has a priority interest over the federal tax lien.

The time period for a redemption after a foreclosure sale, with respect to either a non-judicial or judicial foreclosure, is 120 calendar days or the period allowable for redemption under State law, whichever is longer.

IRS redemptions can benefit both the government and the taxpayer. The goal of redemption is for the property to be resold for an amount substantial enough to pay off the foreclosing instrument and apply funds to the taxpayer's liability. The key to a successful redemption case is locating a guaranteed bidder willing to advance a deposit (generally in the amount of twenty (20) percent) of the amount bid.


I am interested in the statement "The goal of redemption is for the property to be resold for an amount substantial enough to pay off the foreclosing instrument and apply funds to the taxpayer's liability."
I get the general concept of what this is saying, but I don't quite understand the specifics. I assume that the foreclosure instrument referred to is the amount owed to the creditor on that particular property. I am also guessing that the minimum bid in the initial auction that the IRS would accept is the foreclosure amount. In that case the IRS would be hoping to get money out of the sale, and at worst break even. But I don't know for sure if the auctions of IRS seized property works this way.
And then I'm not clear if later exercising their redemption option requires that a high enough bid is found to make a substantial additional contribution toward the overall tax liability compared to the initial sale. In the Nelson/Royal situation it seems like the IRS was apparently justified, since they found a buyer willing to pay almost double what Royal paid. Then again if the IRS gets to decide what is "substantial" without any guidelines, then they could exercise this option any time they want to within the 120 day period, as long at they find someone willing to pay any amount above the original sale amount, effectively giving them the power to make things unpleasant for someone they don't like. I'm not really into government conspiracy, but I did grow up during the Watergate era, so I don't dismiss out of hand the claim on Wikipedia about the IRS without at least looking into whether it's even possible.
To avoid asking multiple questions I tried to distill it into one - could Darrell Royal have ensured that he would be able to keep the Pedernales Country Club for Willie Nelson by meeting a minimum bid (presumably the amount of the foreclosing instrument), or is there really nothing stopping the IRS from cancelling the sale if they can find a higher bidder of any amount within 120 days? If it's the latter then it would seem that the only way for Royal to have ensured that the sale would go through is if he bid an amount equal to Nelson's entire unpaid tax liability, i.e. however much of the original $32 million was still owed after whatever prior sales of other Nelson owned property had taken place. Or at least at a minimum bid an amount that is practically guaranteed to not be later outbid, for example bidding twice the appraised value of the property.
Again this seems to have implications for someone trying to hold onto for example family owned property when it has been seized by the IRS, especially since homestead exceptions apparently don't apply to IRS seizures.
